# MediaRecorder setting output format crash

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I would like to record video using `MediaRecorder` but when i set the output format with `setOutputFormat` method I always get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException at
>   android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method) at
>   android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:416)

The following is the code that I use to prepare the mediarecorder:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
```

**UPDATE** This is the whole stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method)
>   at android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:416)
>   at net.alfdev.demomaps.CameraActivity.prepareVideoRecorder(CameraActivity.java:344)
>   at net.alfdev.demomaps.CameraActivity.buttonCaptureVideo(CameraActivity.java:398)
>   at net.alfdev.demomaps.CameraActivity_$2.onLongClick(CameraActivity_.java:106)
>   at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4802)
>   at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8948)
>   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19795)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Any idea?
thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the whole logcat for that error?

Comment: plz post your logcat...

Comment: Verify if your code is correct in regard of the MediaRecorder state machine (there is an order for calling those methods) - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: I think you haven't called setProfile on the mediaRecorder?

Comment: Bhargav i set the profile on the mediarecorder